# Dynamically reload Materialize Image Slider photos

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, materialize

I'm trying to make my MaterializeCSS image slider dynamically reload photo from different folders as the user switches to another album.
Here is my approach:

```
<script>
    function showPhotos(album) {
        alert("Show photos function is called");
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                var contents = "";
                var count = parseInt(xmlhttp.responseText);
                for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
                    contents += "<li>";
                    contents += ("<img src=\"images/album_" + album + "/" + ("00" + i).slice(-2) + ".jpg\" />");
                    contents += "</li>\r\n";
                }
                document.getElementById("photo-slide").innerHTML = contents;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "/php/gethint.php?q=" + album, false);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

where the ***gethint.php?q=*** basically returns the number of files in a specific folder.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#album1").click(function(){
            showPhotos(1);
            $('.slider').slider({full_width: true, height: 600});
        });
        $("#album2").click(function(){
            showPhotos(2);
            $('.slider').slider({full_width: true, height: 600});
        });
        $("#album3").click(function(){
            showPhotos(3);
            $('.slider').slider({full_width: true, height: 600});
        });
    });
</script>
```

where album1, album2 and album3 are the 3 items in my drop-down list.

The result works fine with the first album selection. Everything works as expected. But when I tried to switch album, the new pictures are loaded too, transitions are fine, but the indicator at the bottom starts acting weird. I need either a fix for my approach, or a better solution for what I need.

Comment: Just found a similar topic that was closed without an answer over in github. https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/1259. I think that guy had the exact same problem that I'm having

Comment: Hi @Tom,
Did you find solution to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

The [MaterializeCSS](http://materializecss.com/carousel.html) carousel doesn't seem to have a 'reinitialize' function.  I wanted to do this myself so I found this to work well enough for my needs:

```
$('.carousel').removeClass('initialized');
$('.carousel').carousel();
```

It is kind of hacky, but if you check out the carousel [src](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/master/js/carousel.js#L30) you'll see a check to avoid double-initializations.  So basically, you remove the *initialized* class from the carousel div, and then initialize the carousel like you do on document ready.

Note that this goes against the authors intentions, so there will most likely be demons.